# How to turn PI4 into a IOT device , discoverable and configurable via mobile app (Wifi P2P or BLE)

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, wifi-direct, p2p

I've created a simple camera system on the PI 4 which I want to be discoverable with a custom android app.

The should find the PI device, then automatically connect, then mobile app will share the WiFi configuration or allow manual input of wifi configuration and then open the camera module for calibration.

Using Wifi Direct (P2P) It should be as seamlessly as possible. Similar to how Google Home or other IOT devices get discovered in app.

Any code examples I can use?

Comment: This question in not a matter of opinion. It is just written in a wishy washy way. If re-written to just ask the question. Then, it will probably easier to comprehend.